# How can this exponential equation be computed

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a mathematical way to solve such equations, besides try and error of course?

$e^{-x} = 1-x/5$

Comment: Try the Lambert w function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

$$ x = W(-5e^{-5})+5 $$

besides the solution $ x=0$.

**Note:** [Lambert $W$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is the solution of the equation

> $$ W(t) e^{W(t)} = t. $$

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Lambart Function...I was really baffled how you got $x = W(-5e^{-5})+5$ in the first place, I had to reverse engineer it to find out how...Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3556914: You are very welcome! Happy to assist.